# Recylerview with multiple view types

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i'm trying to make recyclerview with four viewtypes , each viewtype will represent certain data , my app is for premier league ( football ) , so i have viewtype for goals , yellow card,and red card , 
each string comes with the time of scoring the goal , or getting the yellow card and red card , i'm trying to apply some logic but it is not working for me

- First : this is what i'm trying to achieve 
  [Image that shows how goals , and cards are ordered by the time they happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gShZi.jpg)
- second this is the code i tried to achieve that :

```
       //Splitting Strings
       String[] homeg = hometiming.split(";");
       String[] homeyello = homeyellow.split(";");
       String[] homere = homered.split(";");

       for (String h : homeg) {
           if (!h.equals("")) {

               int subgoals = Integer.parseInt(h.substring(0, 1));

               for (String y : homeyello) {
                   if (!y.equals("")) {

                       int subYellow = Integer.parseInt(y.substring(0, 1));

                       for (String n : homere) {
                           if (!n.equals("")) {
                               int subRed = Integer.parseInt(n.substring(0, 1));

                               /// if goals time is smaller than time of yellow and rec card , show 
                               /// goals
                               if (subgoals < subYellow && subgoals < subRed) {

                                   GoalsItem goalsItem = new GoalsItem();
                                   goalsItem.setHomegoals("goals :" + h + "\n");
                                   consolidatedlist.add(goalsItem);
                               }
                               /// if yellow cards time is smaller than time of goals and red cards , 
                               /// show yellow cards
                               else if (subYellow < subgoals && subYellow < subRed) {

                                   YellowItems yellowItems = new YellowItems();
                                   yellowItems.setHomeyellow("yellow :" + y + "\n");
                                   consolidatedlist.add(yellowItems);
                                }
                               /// if red card time is smaller than time of goals and yellow cards , 
                               /// show red cards
                               else if (subRed < subgoals && subRed < subYellow) {
                                   RedItems redItems = new RedItems();
                                   redItems.setHomered("red : " + n + "\n");
                                   consolidatedlist.add(redItems);

                           } } } } } } }
```

- third : this is my apdapter on bindviewholder

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {

            case TypeItem.TYPE_PHOTO:
                PhotoItem photoItem = (PhotoItem) list.get(position);
                ViewPhoto viewphoto = (ViewPhoto) holder;
                viewphoto.date.setText("" + photoItem.getDate());
                Picasso.with(context).load(photoItem.getPhoto()).fit().into(((ViewPhoto) holder).photo);
                break;

            case TypeItem.TYPE_Goals:
                GoalsItem goalsItem = (GoalsItem) list.get(position);
                ViewGoals viewgoals = (ViewGoals) holder;
                viewgoals.homegoals.setText("" + goalsItem.getHomegoals());
                viewgoals.awaygoals.setText("" + goalsItem.getAwaygoals());

                break;

            case TypeItem.TYPE_Yellow:
                YellowItems yellowItems = (YellowItems) list.get(position);
                ViewYellow viewyellow = (ViewYellow) holder;
                viewyellow.homeyellow.setText("" + yellowItems.getHomeyellow());
                viewyellow.awayyellow.setText("" + yellowItems.getAwayyellow());

                break;
            case TypeItem.TYPE_RED:
                RedItems redItems = (RedItems) list.get(position);
                ViewRed viewred = (ViewRed) holder;
                viewred.homered.setText("" + redItems.getHomered());
                viewred.awayred.setText("" +redItems.getAwayred());
                break;

        }
    }
```

- this is sample of json i'm using for more clarification

```
         "strHomeGoalDetails":"",
         "strHomeRedCards":"",
         "strHomeYellowCards":"13':Luka Milivojevic;",
         "strAwayRedCards":"",
         "strAwayYellowCards":"47':Raheem Sterling;",
         "strAwayGoalDetails":"39':Gabriel Jesus;41':David Silva;",
```

Comment: Could you specify exactly what isn't working for you?

Comment: to be more specific , i included a photo to see above , what i want to acheieve is order goals and card based on the time like shows in the photo above , take look there if you don't mind thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `override getItemViewType(position: Int)` , than by `viewType` in `onCreatecreate`  return different `ViewHolders` (if you need), and than in `onBindViewHolder` do you bindings by your types

For example in your adapter class create map with `typeField: String`, and `key: Int`

```
private val keyMap = HashMap<String, Int>().apply {
    put("FIRST_TYPE", 1)
    put("SECOND_TYPE", 2)
    put("THIRD_TYPE", 3)
}
```

the second step is to override `getItemViewType(position: Int)`

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
return keyMap.get(yourItemList(position).getType())
```

Third step - `override  onCreateViewHolder`

```
 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ResourceViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
           keyMap.get("FIRST_TYPE") -> //create specific ViewHolder
           keyMap.get("SECOND_TYPE") -> //create specific ViewHolder
           //etc
}
```

The last part is to bind `onBindViewHolder`

You can do this the same way as `onCreateViewHolder`

Comment: i already did so , what is not working for me is the code i wrote , i tried to split the strings and then substring the time , convert it to int then compare values of each string( goal , yellow card , red card )  and order the viewtypes but it is not giving me any result . thank you

Comment: I mean i applied all the steps you showed above , should i return the viewtypes in my  activity , what you probably didnt notice , is that i have a time in each string type like this ( goal :  "13':Luka Milivojevic;", yellow card : "strAwayYellowCards":"47':Raheem Sterling;", ) so my logic should be like this : if goal time is bigger than yellow card time , then show goal first , and vice versa , hope you got me . thank you

Comment: @takieddine I think your problem is in your json file. I think your json have to be like that
`"event": {
        "type": "red card",
        "name": "Luka",
       "time": "51",
      "team":"home"
}`
than parse your object a do what you need

Comment: Well for that part you re right , and thats why i face the problem because i contacted the api and they said it is that way and it is not possible to change so i m stuck in between

Comment: @takieddine only way i see in this situation is to parse your json to "event" list at the step of obtaining data in manual way